# @media queries NOT WORKING (While uploaded to Google Drive)

Tags: html, css

NOTE that media queries run perfectly while viewed offline , But it is not working while uploaded to Google Drive and hosted via drive to web..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BROWN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <!-- FONTS -->
    <!-- h1 -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=KoHo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- h2 -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- h3 -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- h4 -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Newsreader&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- a -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- price -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div id = "mainbar">
            <h1>brown</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div id = "contents">
            <div id = "box">
                <img src="iphoneX.jpg"  alt="iphone-image">
                <div id = "description">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>New Apple iPhone 11 (64GB) - Black </h2></li>
                        <li><h3>Price:<span>₹ 53,250.00</span></h3></li>
                        <li><a href="p-id-1.html">Know More</a></li>
                        <li><button type = "submit" id = "buy-now-p-id-1">Buy Now</button></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id = "box" class = "p-id-2">
                <img src="macbook.jpg" alt="mac-book_image">
                <div id = "description">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>New Apple MacBook Pro with Apple M1 Chip</h2></li>
                        <li><h3>Price:<span> ₹ 1,16,790.00</span></h3></li>
                        <li><a href="p-id-2.html">Know More</a></li>
                        <li><button type = "submit" id = "buy-nowp-id-2">Buy Now</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id = "box">
                <img src="iwatch2.jpg" alt="i-watch">
                <div id = "description">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>New Apple Watch SE (GPS + Cellular, 44mm) </h2></li>
                        <li><h3>Price:<span> ₹ 36,900.00</span></h3></li>
                        <li><a href="p-id-3.html">Know More</a></li>
                        <li><button type = "submit" id = "buy-now-p-id-3">Buy Now</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div id = "box">
                <img src="jbl3.jpg" alt="jbl_image">
                <div id = "description">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>JBL Tune 750BTNC by Harman Over-Ear Wireless</h2></li>
                        <li><h3>Price:<span> ₹ 5,799.00</span></h3></li>
                        <li><a href="p-id-4.html">Know More</a></li>
                        <li><button type = "submit" id = "buy-now-p-id-4" >Buy Now</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**THE HTML PAGE LINKS ARE ALL GOOD I TRIPLE CHECKED IT**

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#mainbar {
    display:flex;
    height:90px;
    align-items:center;
}
#mainbar h1 {
    margin-left:100px;
    font-family:'KoHo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 45px;
}
img {
    height:230px;
    width:230px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}
h4 {
    font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}
a {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:red;
}
ul {
    margin-left:30px;
    list-style:none;
    line-height:45px;
}
button {
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
    width:90px;
    height:40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px solid grey;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px black;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    transition : 1s ease-in-out ;
    /* transition-duration:1;  */ 
}
#box {
    height:250px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    border-top:1px solid grey;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
    margin-top:10px;
}
span {
    color:rgb(27, 55, 179);
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
#contents {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#contents #box #p-id-1_description {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
*MEDIA QUERIES NOT SHOWING UP*
@media (max-width:850px) {
    img {
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:700px) {
    img {
        height:180px;
        width:180px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 21px;
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    ul {
        margin-left:30px;
        list-style:none;
        line-height:40px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:550px) {
    img {
        height:150px;
        width:150px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size:16px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    a {
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        color:red;
    }
    ul {
        margin-left:30px;
        list-style:none;
        line-height:35px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:400px) {
    #mainbar h1 {
        margin-left:50px;
        font-family:'KoHo', sans-serif;
        font-size: 45px;
    }
    #box {
        height:180px;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        border-top:1px solid grey;
        border-bottom:1px solid grey;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    img {
        height:125px;
        width:125px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size:15px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    a {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        color:red;
    }
    ul {
        margin-left:30px;
        list-style:none;
        line-height:30px;
    }
} 
@media (max-width:350px) {
    #box {
        height:220px;
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
        border-top:1px solid grey;
        border-bottom:1px solid grey;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    img {
        height:110px;
        width:110px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 10px black;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size:13px;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: 'Newsreader', serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    a {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        color:red;
    }
    ul {
        margin-left:30px;
        list-style:none;
        line-height:30px;
    }
    button {
        color:black;
        background-color:white;
        width:80px;
        height:30px;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:2px solid grey;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 2px black;
        font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
        transition : 1s ease-in-out ;
        /* transition-duration:1;  */ 
    }
}
```

This is working offline but when viewed ig Google Drive the media query desent show up.
[This is the link to that site you can see that the media queries are not showing up](https://udpozizzftxfgtm3kjcqjw-on.drv.tw/www.brown-e.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media screen or use !important and ascend the max-width css order.I mean the smallest width should go top from the ohtres.